# Применение рекурсии при обходе дерева

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проблема в следующем: если я указываю возвращение перед рекурсивным вызовом функции: `return find(node, counter)` - она завершается раньше времени, пропуская первые ветки дерева. Если не указываю: `find(node, counter)` - обходит все узлы, но не возвращает счетчик (counter). Как мне обойти все дерево?

```
def Count(self):
    if not self.Root:
        return 0
    tree = self.Root
    counter = 1
    def find(tree, counter):
        for node in tree.Children:
            counter += 1
            if node.Children:
                return find(node, counter) # this place
        return counter
    count = find(tree, counter)
    return count
```

Comment: Можно упростить: `if self.Root is None:` -> `if not self.Root:` и `if len(node.Children) > 0:` -> `if node.Children:`

Comment: принято, спасибо!;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы составить рекурсивную функцию, нужно думать рекурсивно :)

Допустим у нас уже **есть** корректная функция `find` которая делает то, что нам нужно - считает количество узлов начиная с некоторого корня.

Тогда для текущего узла нам нужно посчитать количество узлов для всех детей, вызвав `find` для каждого, а так же прибавить к этой сумме единицу - текущий узел.

```py
def Count(self):
    def find(tree):
        return 1 + sum(find(node) for node in tree.Children)

    return 0 if self.Root is None else find(self.Root)
```

Comment: принято, спасибо за идею!;)

Answer (score 1):

... решил ситуацию следующим способом. просто изменил суть счетчика...

```
    def Count(self):
        if not self.Root:
            return 0
        tree = self.Root
        counter = [1]
        def find(tree, counter):
            for node in tree.Children:
                counter[0] += 1
                print(node.NodeValue)
                if node.Children:
                    find(node, counter)
            return counter
        count = find(tree, counter)
        return count[0]
```

Comment: Мне кажется дело не в счётчике, а в том, что из строки `return find(node, counter)` надо было убрать `return`.

Comment: ну если это сделать, то значение счетчика не возвращается. я указывал это в проблеме...